# Split string during mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, split, ip, aggregation-framework

I have collection in MongoDB with documents like:

```
{_id : "...", ip : "0.1.10.200", item : "..."}
```

`ip` is IP v4 address. 
I need to group this data by IP. Also, I need to split ip into 4 parts and add additional fields to result from document like:

```
{
    "ip" : "0.1.10.200",
    "ip_part1" : "0",
    "ip_part2" : "1",
    "ip_part3" : "10",
    "ip_part4" : "200",
    "items" : [ 
     ...
    ]
}
```

I'm using aggregation framework for grouping by `ip`. But I don't know how I can split `ip` into parts. `$substr` is not suitable because `ip` address could be:

`"100.110.0.0"
"1.10.100.1"`

So I don't know start and end index for each part of IP-address.

What is the best way to split ip into parts during aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to split string in a aggregation, Think you have to do the last part client side. 
Or store the splitted parts in your document during a save. You could do this utomatically during save.

Update: Its now possible using `$split` aggregation starting 3.4 version.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/